# Edit HTML file, and send HTML Email iOS

Tags: html, ios, file, edit

I have and HTML file which contain a thanks message, I have to append a name, designation and other detail of the user at run time at the end of file, 
Following is the HTML File Content

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CONTENT-TYPE" CONTENT="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<TITLE></TITLE>
<META NAME="GENERATOR" CONTENT="LibreOffice 4.1.3.2 (MacOSX)">
<META NAME="CREATED" CONTENT="20140617;210025154939000">
<META NAME="CHANGED" CONTENT="20140617;210535128806000">
<STYLE TYPE="text/css">
<!--
    @page { margin: 0.79in }
    P { margin-bottom: 0.08in }
    A:link { so-language: zxx }
-->
</STYLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY LANG="en-US" DIR="LTR">
<div style="color:#34495e;">Hi there,</div>
<div style="color:#34495e; margin-left:15px">Thanks Message ..... </div>
<div style="height:10px"></div>
<div>Regards,</div>
<div>QQQQ</div>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I read the file and save the content on a string, I tried to edit the content before sending email, but content is being edit. 
I m using following code

```
NSError* error = nil;
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"ThankEmail" ofType: @"html"];
NSString *res=[[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
[res stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"QQQQ" withString:@"MY NAME"];
NSLog(@"Message String :%@",res);
```

But it has no effect on String :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
[res stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"QQQQ" withString:@"MY NAME"];
```

to

```
res = [res stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"QQQQ" withString:@"MY NAME"];
```

Comment: You beat me by a few seconds.

Comment: @SantaClaus maybe I should deliver your toys next December then?

Comment: I'm not _that_ old, I can get around by myself just fine. ;)

Comment: (facefryingpan) Thank you both of you!

Answer (score 1):

You are using an immutable string.

The `stringByReplacingOccurancesOfString` method *returns* the new string.

I believe this will do the trick:

```
res = [res stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"QQQQ" withString:@"MY NAME"];
```